# VBA Visible range paste using usedrange offset

Tags: excel, vba

I'm attempting to paste specific columns using a usedrange offset so that my pasted data won't overwrite what is already there. I keep getting the error "Method or Member data not found" and I can't figure out how to correct it. Everything looks okay to me. It's probably something small I'm missing but here is what I have...

```
 lrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AE$10000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="NA"
        Set sh = Worksheets("Country")
        Set ppage = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PPage")
        Set rang = ppage.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0)

        sh.Range("A1:C" & lrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        rang("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        sh.Range("S1:U" & lrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        rang("D1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

it appears the issue is coming in around the `ppage.rang` statement for pasting my values. Any help or push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!!

Comment: you are saying `worksheets("Country").thisworkbook.worksheets("page")`  you just need `ppage.usedrange.offset(....` or  `sh.usedrange.offset(....`  Are both sheets in the same book also, you are saying where Page is, but country will be assumed in the activeworkbook.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav I've updated the code. Yes they sheets are all on the same workbook. Also with the changes I made above I'm getting an "Invalid procedure call or arguement" error on the pastespecial line.

Comment: Where do you populate `lrow`????

Comment: `rang("A1").PasteSpecial` == `rang.cells(1,1).PasteSpecial` I think

Comment: lrow is populated before all the main statements above. It's literally run just before. I've added it to the code to show placement

Comment: Same error using your suggestion.

Comment: What line errors?

Comment: `rang("A1").pastespecial...` I don't think it likes something to do with my rang statement. I have rang set as range.

Comment: You should get out of the habit of using `ActiveSheet`. Might not be what you think it is. Is there definitely something on PPage sheet?

Comment: I said that you need to change this to be `rang.cells(1,1)`

Comment: @SJR for the ppage there is a title line (row 1). There is also the possibility of more being in the page. The reason I'm using used range and offset is to accommodate the fact that there may be something on that page and if so to take the next available line to copy the data to.

Comment: Try Nathan's answer then.

Comment: yep working on it now. it's mostly working. issue is the copy is taking my title line when filtering column A. Using offset seems to make it skip row 1. Just making some tweaks I think will make it work. I really appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are offsetting the whole `usedrange`  `Set rang=range("a" & ppage.usedrange.rows.count+1)` instead.

```
Sub x()

Dim r As Excel.Range
Dim ppage As Excel.Worksheet

Set ppage = Worksheets("sheet1")

ppage.Range("$A$1:$J$10").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="NA"

Set r = ppage.Range("a" & ppage.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1)

ppage.Range("$A$1:$J$10").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

r.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End Sub
```